# wxWidgets 3.1.4 - Transparency Problem with XPM images

Tags: image, wxwidgets

After upgrading to version 3.1.4 on Windows 10 (using VS 2017), I see that XPM images with transparency don't show correctly on wxRibbonButtonBar. As an example, the comparison of 3.1.3 and 3.1.4 is shown below:

[image]

The code adding image is briefly as follows:

```
auto ButtonBar_BoxandWhisker = new wxRibbonButtonBar(PanelBoxandWhisker);
ButtonBar_BoxandWhisker->AddButton(ID_PLOT_BOXWHISKER_HOR, "Horizontal", wxBitmap(plot_boxwhiskerchart_xpm), "hor");
```

I generate XPM images using GIMP. Part of the above-shown XPM image is:

```
static char * plot_boxwhiskerchart_xpm[] = {
"32 32 4 1",
"   c None",
".  c #000000",
"+  c #FF7F27",
"@  c #880015",
".                               ",
".                               ",
```

Any ideas welcomed.

Comment: This looks like a regression and hence a bug, please report it on wxTrac. As usual, providing a minimal patch reproducing the problem in the ribbon sample would be very welcome. TIA!

Comment: Just as a side note: If I use images from wxArtProvider things work fine. As I can see wxArtProvider uses XPM images as well. I wonder why those work with no problems.

Comment: A dirty trick for the above shown image is: `char* bgVal = (char*)"  c #D7E3F0";` and then `plot_boxwhiskerchart_xpm[1] = bgVal;`. This replaces the `"   c None"` (which should be at the 2nd position and GIMP produces XPM images thus way) and therefore "alleviates" the problem.